# save mysql logins

Tags: command-line, passwords, login, mysql, password-management

I have to log into multiple MYSQL DB's on different hosts via mysql cli.  is it possible to save these logins so I don't have to trackdown/remember the credentials?

Comment: do you connect to the mysql network port or ssh in and connect to the db locally?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3889/is-it-possible-to-have-passwords-configured-per-database-or-per-host-in-my-cnf for an easier way to do this with the default `~/.my.cnf` file and `mysql --defaults-group-suffix`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on a discussion at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17627 I use the following method to automatically log into different mysql servers:

File /path/to/my-host1-cnf.txt

```
[client]
host="hostname1"
user="username1"
password="password1"
database="database1"
```

File /path/to/my-host2-cnf.txt

```
[client]
host="hostname2"
user="username2"
password="password2"
database="database2"
```

Connect to host1, database1 with saved credentials above:

```
mysql --defaults-file="/path/to/my-host1-cnf.txt"
```

Connect to host2, database2 with saved credentials above:

```
mysql --defaults-file="/path/to/my-host2-cnf.txt"
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: This looks like it might be what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can always create an aliases to it

```
alias db1='mysql -uUsername1 -pPasswordSecure1 -hHosname1 DatabaseName1'
alias db2='mysql -uUsername2 -pPasswordSecure2 -hHosname2 DatabaseName2'
```

etc..

And put them into your

> .bash_aliases
>
> .barsh_profile

or

> .bash_rc

But this doesn't solve the security issue! Even if you put "good" permission on your bash files it doesn't mean it isn't plain text :(

Comment: This is not safe! "This is convenient but insecure. On some systems, your password becomes visible to system status programs such as ps that may be invoked by other users to display command lines." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html

Comment: Putting your password in plain text is _never_ a good idea. Even if you secure your files it still executes as a command which will show up in `ps aux`, your .bash_history, etc.